# Facebook PHP throwing exception (#803)

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#803) Cannot query users by their username (naitik) thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\facebook-php-sdk-master\src\base_facebook.php on line 1325

please help me to slove this problem...

Comment: That error message is clear enough. What solution do you expect us to provide?

Comment: Please give us more information so we can help you with your problem. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry,My English is bad but I want to learn to develop android application.
I load file from https://github.com/facebookarchive/facebook-php-sdk
and want to login with facebook pass my application.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if you didn't understand what Hobo Sapiens was saying, your error is because you use username to query. 
To be able to query you must use an id... user-id/page-id/post-id/ etc.

Good luck with learning!